# EF core: Setting a DbContext connection string without using operation UseSqlServer

Tags: connection-string, dbcontext, ef-core-2.0

Is there a way how to set a concrete connection string into the DBContext without using the extension method SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer? What if I don't know a type of db server I will use?

Comment: If you don't know the type of the db server, then you have to determine it yourself and then use the corresponding `UseXyz` extension method provided by the supported (from the installed packages) db providers. This is "by design".

Comment: I needn't know it in EF6! All I need to do in EF is set a connection string.

Comment: And? You should probably first have read that the EF Core is completely new framework having many differences compared to EF6 before deciding to use it. And once you decided to use it, then you should accept its rules/limitations/differences.

Comment: @user3392683 You didn't know it in EF6 but it was set behind the scenes! when you install EF6 in a project it automatically sets the appropriate provider in the `app.config` file much like what we do with `.UseSqlServer` in ef core

Comment: @hesam-kashefi: So the conclusion is:
.NET: Adjustable in config.
.NET Core: Hardcoded.
Isn't it?